# How to enable UPI payment part in webview in android app

Tags: android, android-webview, payment-gateway, upi, instamojo

I have an e-commerce website where at the end I need to make payment, where it shows 4 UPI payment app options (BHIM,phonePe,gPay,paytm).but when I try to click those UPI app option buttons, it shows error as **Webpage not available..webpage at intent://pay?pa=..net: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME ....**
I have tried url.startswith("upi") but it is not working.... How can I fix this ?